# Get the same input File format after Encryt --> base64 Encode-->Encrypted file -->base64decode-->Decrypt--->decrypted file

Tags: java, encryption, format, base64

I'm converting a text file to enc file in the following way:

1. Read through file input stream.
2. Encrypt
3. Encode using base 64.
4. Use File output stream to write to .enc file.
5. Read .enc file through file input stream
6. Decode using base 64.
7. d e crypt
8. Use File output stream to write to text file.

I'm not able to get the same output format as the input file. The output is the same.

```java
//Encrypt
inFile = new FileInputStream(path + "/" + fileName);
outFile = new FileOutputStream(encfileName);
byte[] input = new byte[64];
            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = inFile.read(input)) != -1) {
                byte[] output = cipher.update(input, 0, bytesRead);
                if (output != null)

                    outFile.write(Base64.getEncoder().encode(output));
            }

            byte[] output = cipher.doFinal();
            if (output != null)
                outFile.write(Base64.getEncoder().encode(output));

//Decrypt
fis = new FileInputStream(path + "/" + encryptedFile);
            fos = new FileOutputStream(decryptedFile);
            byte[] in = new byte[64];
            int read;
            while ((read = decoder.wrap(fis).read(in)) != -1) {
                byte[] output = cipher.update(in, 0, read);
                if (output != null)
                    fos.write(output);
            }

            byte[] output = cipher.doFinal();
            if (output != null)
                fos.write(output);
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Use a wrapping encoder as well. As it is you are inserting padding characters and base64 characters partially containing bits into the encrypted data.

Comment: Thank you Maarten. I figured out the input text file format in notepad is different in different systems.There is nothing I can do about that.